# Pronounciation of numbers in 'year... at school'?

Tags: pronunciation

How do you pronounce the number in the following sentence?

> I'm in year 5 at school.

Is it "five" or "fifth"?

Comment: year 5 vs 5th year.

Comment: Year (number) five.

Comment: To expand on @k1eran's comment if the number comes _after_ the  noun then it is being used, essentially, as a name so it is the _cardinal_ form and it is pronounced 'year five'. If it comes _before_ the noun then it is used, essentially, as an adjective so it is in the _ordinal_ form and us pronounced "fifth year". However when the ordinal form is written the number should be foĺlowed by the ordinal suffix and be written "5th year".

Comment: Thank you all of you, especially Boldben for the clear explanation!